# How to switch from Microsoft Word to a Firefox Browser(already launched) using Microsoft Coded UI?

Tags: c#, testing, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests

I am using Microsoft Coded UI 2012 to automate a Web Based application. I am using Selenium WebDriver dlls for this purpose. My requirement is as follows:
1. Launch Firefox.
2. Launch Microsoft Word.
3. Enter some values in Microsoft Word.
4. Switch back to Firefox. (This is where it fails)
5. Do some operation in Firefox.

Please find a snippet of the code being used below:

```
Driver driverObj = new Driver();
driverObj.InitiateDriver(); //creates a new Firefox driver
String strWindowHandle = driverObj.driver.WindowHandles.ToString(); //getting the windows handle of the firefox browser
this.UIMap.RecordedMethod3(); //recorded method to interact with Microsoft Word
driverObj.driver.WindowHandles.IndexOf(strWindowHandle);//switches the handle back to Firefox
driverObj.GoogleSearch();//performs operation on firefox
this.UIMap.RecordedMethod4();//Recorded method to close Microsoft word.
```

Now the issue that I am facing is: When the Microsoft word is launched, it does not switch back to Firefox window. However, after changing the windows handle, the operations on the firefox window are performed in the background. I want to display the operations performed in the foreground by switching to the Firefox window. Coded UI is failing to do so. However the test passes as all the actions are performed.

Comment: Are you sure the `IndexOf` method on `WindowHandles` actually performs an action in the user space?  Typically an `IndexOf` method simply returns an Int32 (index of an element in an array or list) without performing any actions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SetForegroundWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to activate the firefox window and put it on top, if the handle is valid:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. But this works the same way as the following piece of code in the Code snippet above: driverObj.driver.WindowHandles.IndexOf(strWindowHandle); The firefox window is still not visible in the foreground. All the operations all carried out in the background. @Saleh Yusefnejad

Answer (score 0):

Since usually codedui set the focus on the control he is operating - try using the SetFocus() method on the firefox window you want displayed, or clicking it with the mouse -since this operatins cannot be performed on a hidden window.